# RANK() on 2 Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to RANK Data based on 2 Columns.

Firstly, I want to take the MOST RECENT JobTitle (example field) based on the Last modified Data

```
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC) AS [Rank]
```

However, If the JobTitle is NULL, I want to take the existing record / keep the data.

If I put a `WHERE` clause to say `WHERE jobTitle IS NOT NULL` it will remove new records from the dataset that may not have JobTitle (example field) populated yet! - So I can't go with this approach.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - See sample DataSet below for context.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just remove null values when you want to exclude them?

Comment: If I exclude NULL values when there's only 1 record for an Email - When I INSERT into a final table,  that new Email won't be included

Answer (score 0):

Order non-`NULL` values first, and *then* by the last updated:

```sql
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Email
             ORDER BY CASE WHEN JobTitle IS NULL THEN 0 END,
                      LastUpdated DESC) AS [Rank] --The NEWID() makes no sense in the `ORDER BY`.
```

Comment: Thank you - I've removed the NEWID() from the Question as it was a mistake

Comment: Unfortunately, in some cases this solution assigns multiple rows to the same RANK().

Comment: Yes, it will do; that's what `RANK` does. If you don't want rows with the same number, you don't want `RANK`, @Moose , you want `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Row_Number() Works perfectly! Thanks @Larnu